Is there a name for SQL Injection when it's done on purpose?
I need to concatenate strings to generate a query to execute, mainly because parameters cannot be used in the places I need to.
For example, FETCH NEXT <n> ROWS clause in DB2 does not accept JDBC parameters but only a string in its place. The following code crashes:
int limit = 100;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SALARY FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY"); // crashes
ps.setInt(limit);

While the following code works:
int limit = 100;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SALARY FETCH NEXT " + limit
  + " ROWS ONLY"); // works

This is technically "SQL Injection" (I think) but it's on purpose and also safe.
Is there a better name to describe this instead of "SQL Injection"? I need to explain this to the security guys and I don't want to be barked at.

It is called Dynamic SQL

@BartMcEndree I don't think there is any fundamental difference between the two terms. What OP referes to as "unsafe" injection would be termed malicious SQL injection whereas this would be benign. Ultimately if you have dynamic SQL then it's an injection of data directly into the query, but what you inject depends on the level of control of those dynamic variables and whether they are escaped properly.

It is called Dynamic SQL. Here are some examples in SQL Server
https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/

You're just building SQL statements from data. It's not SQL injection. The SQL injection would be if your limit variable came from the outside.
